# how to limit amount of rows in jsonb_agg & jsonb_build_object

Tags: postgresql, query

I have this query:

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('me_id', me_id)) from message
```

and I get the following result:

[image]

However I want to limit the amount of objects in the array to a certain number like 3.
How can I do this? Adding `LIMIT 3` is **not working**.

Answer (score 3):

`LIMIT 3` will work just fine if you add it in the right fashion, that is *before* the rows are aggregated:

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('me_id', me_id))
FROM (SELECT me_id FROM message LIMIT 3) AS subquery;
```